# Regular expression for special characters and numericals

Tags: php, regex

Want a regular expression that matches only special characters and numericals..

Consider an example

```
$sting1 = '($001)';
$sting2 = '($001test)';
```

So only $string1 should match in this case and not the second one.
As second string has alphabets present in it, that should not match..

Comment: Instead of "only numeric and special characters", you should look for something that matches "no alphabetical character".

Comment: Thanks.. But this doesn't make me reach there.

Comment: Show your attempt please

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
preg_match('/^\P{L}+$/u', $str);
```

Where `\P{L}` stands for any character that is not a letter.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a `PCRE` regex which can match special characters, numericals and white space.

```
[^[:alpha:]]+
```

If you need to omit whitespaces then,

```
[^[:alpha:]\s]+
```

You can check out the [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/nP5tE0/1).